# Issue while inserting multiple rows in one MySQL column- PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

The query syntax is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO sent (username,password) VALUES 
 ('user','user2','user3','user4','user5','user6'),
 ('pass','pass2','pass3','pass4','pass5','pass6')
```

Resource: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

The mysql_error() always showing me this:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I have no idea what should I do. Now it's time to ask you about this.

Comment: In this case I have to insert in each column 6 values, and I have two columns to operate.

Comment: You need to format it as `INSERT INTO table (field1,field2) VALUES ('user', 'pass'),('user2','pass2')` and so on

Comment: Ok I got the idea, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified 2 columns with 6 values. The number of columns and values has to match. What you want is this:

```
INSERT INTO sent (username,password) VALUES ('user','pass'),('user2','pass2'),('user3','pass3'),('user4','pass4'),('user5','pass5'),('user6','pass6')
```

See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) for more details:

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`